# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'agCKImageAsset'

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm using [AGCKImage](https://github.com/agibson73/AGCKImage) to download images from cloud kit

```
  self.img_ProfilePic.agCKImageAsset(record.recordID, assetKey: "profilePic")

  self.img_Cover.agCKImageAsset(record.recordID, assetKey: "coverPic")
```

However I am getting the following error, Value of type UIImageView has no member 'agCKImageAsset'

Comment: Did you import the library into the current file?